# Use Monte Carlo to produce new 'p' correlated data from existing data

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, forecasting, markov-chain-montecarlo, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

As mentioned above, I have a problem where I need to generate new data Y from an existing data X such that Y is p correlated to X.

I know their are several ways to do it but I want to know if monte Carlo simulation could be used to achieve this goal.
If it is possible, could you point me in the right direction so that I can learn more about it and implement it too?

```
Example: data is X = [2, 4, 9, 10]
```

> Generate new Y such that it has 4 values and it is p=0.75 percent correlate to X.

Comment: Correlation is not a percentage - it goes from -1 to 1. The square of correlation can be construed as a percentage

Comment: Yup that's my mistake, let me change it to say it's 0.75 correlated

Comment: It still says 'percent' at the end of the question.

Comment: I think considering a linear model $Y = \alpha X + \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ are i.i.d. could be a good way to do so. Now you just need to find the adequate value of $\alpha$ using what you know on correlation...